# Why does the area of overlap with st_intersection not match my expectation?

Tags: r, gps, overlapping-features, sf

I'm using the protected area shape files from [Protected Planet](https://www.protectedplanet.net/country/SZ) for Swaziland/ Eswatini.

I calculate a home range (95% kernel density) and want to measure the overlap in area between this and the protected areas. When I do so the area of overlap is greater than the area of the home range which is not possible. I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Here's my code:

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(amt)
library(sf)
library(spex)

#' load in the protected areas
merged_Africa = read_sf("shape//eswatini//WDPA_Apr2020_SWZ-shapefile-polygons.shp")
st_crs(merged_Africa) <- 4326
st_crs(merged_Africa)
merged_Africa_tranform <- st_transform(merged_Africa, "ESRI:102022")

#' location data
x_ <- c(707692, 707589, 707998, 708407, 708916, 709415)
y_ <- c(-3030991,-3031423,-3031640,-3031750,-3032508,-3037158)
mydata <- data.frame(x_, y_)

# transform to trk
trk <-
  mk_track(mydata,
           .x = x_,
           .y = y_,
           crs = CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

#' calculate home range area
kde_shape_1 <- trk %>%
  hr_kde(., levels = c(0.95))
hr_area(kde_shape_1) / 1e6 # 52.00846

#' convert raster to polygon
psf <- qm_rasterToPolygons(kde_shape_1$ud, na.rm = TRUE)

#' measure the intersection
intersection <-
  st_intersection(psf$geometry, merged_Africa_tranform$geometry)
sum(st_area(intersection)) / 1e6 # 61.21044
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure it is what you are looking for but let's give it a try. I run your code, plotting each step so I could analyze graphically the different outputs:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(amt)
library(sf)
library(spex)

#' load in the protected areas
mycrs <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "

merged_Africa = read_sf("pathToFile/WDPA_Jun2020_SWZ-shapefile-polygons.shp")
st_crs(merged_Africa) <- 4326
merged_Africa_tranform <- st_transform(merged_Africa, mycrs)
st_crs(merged_Africa_tranform)
```

Plotting it I get:

[image: Figure 1]

The next steps on your code will throw the next result:

```
#' location data
x_ <- c(707692, 707589, 707998, 708407, 708916, 709415)
y_ <- c(-3030991,-3031423,-3031640,-3031750,-3032508,-3037158)
mydata <- data.frame(x_, y_)

# transform to trk
trk <-
  mk_track(mydata,
           .x = x_,
           .y = y_,
           crs = CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

#' calculate home range area
kde_shape_1 <- trk %>%
  hr_kde(., levels = c(0.95))
hr_area(kde_shape_1) / 1e6 # 52.00846
```

[image: Figure 2]

Which I believe is the home area you are defining. Then you do the following:

```
psf <- qm_rasterToPolygons(kde_shape_1$ud, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If we plot it, we get:

[image: Figure 3]

Which I'm guessing is not what you want and might be the origin of your problems. It seems that the function `qm_rasterToPolygons` uses the whole bounding box of the raster to create a grid of squared polygons (see next figure) rather than creating a polygon with the shape of the home area in figure 2.

[image: Figure 4]

If, instead, we use the function `hr_isopleths` as follows:

```
test <- hr_isopleths(kde_shape_1)
```

And we plot it, we obtain the same case as in figure 2 but with the area defined as a polygon with which we can work. Calculating the intersection again as:

```
intersection <-
  st_intersection(test$geometry, merged_Africa_tranform$geometry)
sum(st_area(intersection)) / 1e6
```

We now obtain an area of `34.68964 [m^2]`

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was after. I double checked it by reducing the level of the kernel to 0.1, this gives a smaller area of 1.437821 km2 which is contained fully within the protected area so the `st_intersection` line gives the same value for the area.